# Can parameter sniffing happen in other RDBMSs, not just SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, rdbms, parameter-sniffing

I just found out that when googling for the parameter sniffing, SQL server is also on the recommended search list but not other RDBMS such as Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL. Even in this community, [parameter-sniffing](/questions/tagged/parameter-sniffing) tag almost comes with [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server), but not for the others.

Is parameter sniffing just a SQL Server thing? If so, why is that? If not, what is the reason that parameter sniffing is almost only linked with SQL Server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? Parameter sniffing is a feature of the Optimizer. Different RDBMSs will have different implementations with different terminology, but are ultimately compatible features. [Does oracle database suffer from parameter sniffing issue](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198443/does-oracle-database-suffer-from-parameter-sniffing-issue)

Comment: @AMtwo Partially. It doesn't answer the last part of my question: `If not, what is the reason that parameter sniffing is almost only linked with SQL Server?` Should I change my question to remove the duplicated part?

Comment: "parameter sniffing" is just the SQL Server terminology. That *term* is unique to SQL Server. The *concept* is not. (In Oracle, it's called "peeking")

Comment: @AMtwo Ah, that might explains the last part of my question. Thank you. I wish I could accept your comment as the answer.